# Collisions issues of CharaterController with other box colliders

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a Player with a CharacterCollider & Coins with box collider. When my player collides with coin, then i m disabling coin in `OnControllerCollideHit()` with `hit.gameObject.active = false` (where hit = coin gameObject).

But still i m getting some back force or a kind of jerk when i collide with coin.

How can i remove that jerk or force on player collision with any coin box collider.?

I did a lot of research on Google & some forums, but can't find related to this issue.

Any Code will be appreciated.

Thankx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this issue with a trick.

I **added an empty child GameObject** with `Box collider` & `Rigidbody` in my **Player GameObject** & increase the collider area that cover my player collider.

This will make me to `react before i collide with player collider`. And i m **handling Coin collision** & **other collision** with `empty GameObject collider`.

I think this solution might probably help other people on Here. Gud Luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you Don't use Trigger, I suggest check on trigger on Box collider in your Player Object. then OnTriggerEnter function will called when collide with coin.